# Where do Maven look for springMVC jars when working with eclipse(maven plugin installed)

Tags: eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, maven, spring-mvc

I am using m2e plugin.
Just stuck at one point when maven search for springMVC jar files where it would be searching.
In /web-inf/lib or in project build path.
Where should I put those jars

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven looks for jars in its [repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).

Therefore you don't need download jars manually when using Maven, it will automatically download jars from remote repository and put it to the local repository on your machine.

Comment: Thankyou for you answer.I have one more query.Since I created a Maven Project under eclipse,configure spring dependencies in pom.xml.Now,How can I create a springmvc project?Do I need to create separate dynamic web project and if so,How can I integerate maven into it in order to use dependencies

Comment: Maven projects with  `<packaging>war</packaging>` in `pom.xml` should be converted to Dynamic Web Project automatically. Make sure that `m2e-wtp` plugin is installed and click `Update Project Configuration`. But if you want separate project for Spring MVC, you can create it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maven uses "settings.xml" file to find out your project repositories. and resolve dependencies(every jar files that you need) from those repositories.

more about  [seetings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) and also
[this one](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) .

After downloading required jar file for first time, maven puts it in your ***local repository*** in:

${user-home}/.m2/repository.